# Duda sobre el uso malloc() y acceso a memoria

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo un par de dudas.

1ª:

```
int *ptr;

ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)); // ¿es lo mismo poner [*ptr / ptr] en sizeof?
```

2ª:

```
 ptr = realloc(ptr, 3 * sizeof(*ptr));

 for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    *(ptr+i) = i;
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr+i));
```

Si al poner un mayor numero de elementos a rellenar en memoria (10 en for) funciona (en output printf), ¿porqué especificar cantidad en realloc, o usarla ya puestos? ¿Hay alguna desventaja en rellenar elementos que salen fuera del espacio de memoria "reservado"?

Answer (score 3):

> Si al poner un mayor numero de elementos a rellenar en memoria (10 en `for`) funciona ...

Funciona ... **aparentemente** y **de pura suerte**.

Eso es lo que se conoce como *comportamiento indefinido*: no está especificado en ninguna parte lo que va a pasar, y, de hecho, puede pasar *casi cualquier cosa*.

Al hacer eso, tal y como dices, rellenas elementos fuera del espacio reservado. Las grandes preguntas que deberías hacerte son ...

1. ¿ Que había ahí **antes** ?
2. Lo que escriba ahí ... ¿ permanecerá ahí, o podría *perderse* ?

La primera es fácil de contestar: **ni idea**; igual estás *machacando* datos internos de la librería, o datos que tu mismo has reservado con anterioridad usando `malloc( )` o `calloc( )`, ..

La segunda, pues casi igual: estás accediendo a memoria que no has reservado, por lo tanto ... puede ser reservada por llamadas posteriores a `malloc( )` y `calloc( )`, y, consecuentemente, **tú mismo** puedes **sobrescribir** lo que has puesto ahí ... sin querer.

En resumen: **no hagas eso**. Y, de forma mas genérica: **evita a toda costa los comportamientos indefinidos**.

#### Nota:

Ten presente que posibles errores no tienen que producirse inmediatamente. Si sobreescribes algo importante, el error se producirá cuando ese algo sea usado ... lo cual puede pasar 1 segundo, 1 minuto, o 1 hora después de que tú lo hayas sobreescrito. Por eso, al principio, puse *aparentemente*.

Answer (score 3):

> Si al poner un mayor numero de elementos a rellenar en memoria (10 en for) funciona (en output printf), ¿porqué especificar cantidad en realloc, o usarla ya puestos? ¿Hay alguna desventaja en rellenar elementos que salen fuera del espacio de memoria "reservado"?

Vamos a suponer que quieres hacer un viaje con familiares y amigos, haces una reserva en un hotel para 10 personas pero poco después de hacer la reserva le dices que en realidad sois 3, ¡pero al final os presentáis los 10!.

Los empleados del hotel fueron informados de que se iba a presentar un grupo de 10 personas, así que prepararon 10 habitaciones contiguas en la misma planta; poco después se enteraron de que se cancelaron 7 reservas pero no pasa nada, simplemente marcaron en los registros que tenían 7 habitaciones disponibles que antes no lo estaban.

Llegáis tus amigos y familiares al hotel, en recepción os dan 3 llaves para las 3 habitaciones que habéis reservado, vais a vuestra planta y 7 de tus acompañantes entran en su habitación derribando la puerta... al fin y al cabo no os han dado 10 llaves si no 3; están felizmente deshaciendo su maleta cuando otros clientes llegan a las habitaciones que ellos creían que les correspondía pero se las encuentran ocupadas por tus amigos y familiares.

Los clientes, indignados, van a la recepción del hotel para decir que sus habitaciones  están ocupadas por unos salvajes que han destrozado la puerta; el personal del hotel se alarma y va rápidamente allí descubriendo que efectivamente, una reserva de 3 habitaciones está usando 10 habitaciones, así que tienen que tomar una decisión:

1. Da igual que los clientes reservaran esas 7 habitaciones, tus amigos y familiares llegaron antes.
2. Las habitaciones reservadas pertenecen a quien las reserva, tus amigos y familiares las están ocupando ilegitimamente.
3. Nos da igual todo, mejor prendemos fuego al hotel.

---

Tu código está en la misma situación, podría ser que tu sistema decida que no pasa nada por usar memoria que no has reservado. Podría ser que nadie fuese a usar esa memoria que estás ocupando ilegitimamente. E incluso podría ser que toda la situación le resulte inaceptable y decida formatear tu disco duro como venganza.

Así que, jamás hagas algo así. Usa la memoria que reservas, ni más ni menos.