# Indice fuera de los limites en c

Tags: c++, array, c

Verán, tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numeros[1];

int indice_numeros = 0;

int main() {

    int i;

    numeros[indice_numeros] = 8;
    indice_numeros++;

    numeros[indice_numeros] = 5;
    indice_numeros++;

    numeros[indice_numeros] = 2;
    indice_numeros++;

    for(i=0;i<indice_numeros;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numeros[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Y al ejecutarlo me muestra lo siguiente:

```
valor en la posicion 0: 8
valor en la posicion 1: 5
valor en la posicion 2: 2
```

Si se supone que el arreglo numeros solo tiene un elemento como es que puedo agregarle mas elementos si estoy fuera de los limites?. Porque no me da ningún error?

Comment: Relacionado: [Duda sobre el uso malloc( ) y acceso a memoria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243644/duda-sobre-el-uso-malloc-y-acceso-a-memoria)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No te da un error porque C y C++ están basados en la filosofía de que el programador sabe lo que hace y que calcula correctamente los índices y no accede donde no toca. Así que no hay control en tiempo de ejecución de que posiciones se acceden, lo cual permite que el programa se ejecute más rápido (no se ejecutan instrucciones para revisar estas cosas).

Así que el programa se continuará ejecutando, pero C y C++ no explican qué pasará: es lo que se denomina Comportamiento indefinido (para los ingleses, *Undefined behavior* o UB). Igual no pasa nada. Igual se cuelga el programa. Y no tiene porqué pasar lo mismo en cada ejecución, ni en cada plataforma.

Esta filosofía de diseño es común para muchas operaciones de C y C++ sobre todo a bajo nivel, aunque las últimas versiones han ido añadiendo formas alternativas de operar que añaden más controles sobre errores de programación.